# Parse server clone install

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, parse-platform

I clone Repo parse server from [parse-server-example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) and add run mongo db and also install nodejs pacakge via `npm install`, But when i want to run app with `npm start` print this error in terminal!!

How i can fix this issue ? it's about nodejs version or what?
[image]

Here is my index.js file:

```js
// Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;


var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'app',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'master', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('Make sure to star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

And by install `babel-cli` and run show me this:

```html
/Users/sajad/Sites/parse/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/babel-polyfill/lib/index.js:14
  throw new Error("only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed");
        ^
Error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sajad/Sites/parse/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/babel-polyfill/lib/index.js:14:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:134:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sajad/Sites/parse/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:9:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because this module(or more correctly, a dependency of your module) is using the const keyword which isn't available in your node version (v0.12). Full support for the const keyword came in v6 of node which arrived just this week.

Alternatively you could transpile your project using [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/)

If you go with the babel route you could do the following in your project root folder

```
npm install -g babel-cli
babel-node index.js
```

See [babel usage page](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) for more information on how to use babel correctly.

EDIT: In the documentation you provided it explicitly tells you that you must have at least node v4.3 and that you should run the project with the command "npm start". So i'm guessing that this project already has babel, you're just running it incorrectly and with the incorrect node version.

Comment: Did you try using node 4.3 and not running with babel?